# Keeping Toolbar visible in ListView with Android Studio template

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Using Android Studio 2.1.1, and presupposing that the templates offered are best (or at least sufficient) practice, I wondered how and why the toolbar is not available/visible when I create a simple app from scratch, and how to have the Toolbar show in the ListView.  The target API's include 15 and up.

The process I used was to create a new app, Minimum SDK API15,  and select "Basic Activity" in the gallery, it creates activity_main.xml and content_main.xml, neither of which do I alter.  The Basic Activity includes a floating action button (an easy way to launch a new activity).   I create "MyListActivity.java", which extends `ListActivity`, and I call that from "MainActivity.java" when the floating action bar is clicked.

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ListView myListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myListView = getListView();
        String[] osArray = { "Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux","Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux","Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux","Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux" };

        int x = android.R.layout.list_content;
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        myListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

When the list comes-up, there is no toolbar.

[image: list without toolbar]

I have made attempts to use a layout with a style that includes a toolbar, but since some of this is 'under the covers', I've not been successful at finding the right way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Bro you need to add two statement after the setcontentview

```
Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and in your xml include Appbar layout before your listview

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

:) happy to help :)

Comment: How would this work?  Where would I put the layouts you posted?  I have no xml file layout to alter, since I'm using stock "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1".  I've already tried making a copy of that, but it puts the toolbar on every item in the list!  And if I extended AppCompactActivity, I could use setSupportActionBar, but I'm extending ListActivity.

Comment: Hey @Dale can you help me in my question, you seem to be pro in Android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901197/collapse-toolbar-with-a-button-but-the-button-should-move-as-the-collapsible-tex

Answer (score 0):

I decided to search "appcompatlistactivity", which the Google machine offered-up "AppCompat ListActivity" and found [this link](https://github.com/ganadist/AndroidApiDemo/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/apis/AppCompatListActivity.java).

What it does is implement AppCompatCallback in the class that extends ListActivity.  What it does is create an AppCompatDelegate in the onCreate() method, then overrides various methods such that not only does it call the super version, it also calls the delegate version.

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity implements AppCompatCallback {
    private AppCompatDelegate mAppCompatDelegate;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ListView myListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mAppCompatDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);
        mAppCompatDelegate.installViewFactory();
        mAppCompatDelegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myListView = getListView();
        String[] osArray = { "Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux","Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux","Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux","Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux" };

        int x = android.R.layout.list_content;
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        myListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAppCompatDelegate.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return mAppCompatDelegate.getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
        mAppCompatDelegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return mAppCompatDelegate.getMenuInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        mAppCompatDelegate.setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        mAppCompatDelegate.setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        mAppCompatDelegate.setContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        mAppCompatDelegate.addContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        mAppCompatDelegate.onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
        super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
        mAppCompatDelegate.setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mAppCompatDelegate.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAppCompatDelegate.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mAppCompatDelegate.onDestroy();
    }

    public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
        mAppCompatDelegate.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Override
    public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

It works.  Not sure if it's optimal, or "the right way", but I'll take it.

[image: list with tool bar]